# How to provide headers to Swagger UI?

Tags: angular, swagger, swagger-ui

I need to provide this header

```json
{
  x-api-key: 'something'
}
```

to my URL in Swagger UI. But there is no documentation for this.

I'm using Angular 9 & here is my code.

```js
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
      dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
      layout: 'BaseLayout',
      presets: [
        SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
        SwaggerUIBundle.SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
      ],
      docExpansion: 'none',
      operationsSorter: 'alpha'
      url: 'https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json'
    });
```

Comment: Does your OpenAPI file define a security scheme for `x-api-key`? ([OAS3 example](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/api-keys/), [OAS2 example](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/api-keys/))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code worked for me:

```
requestInterceptor:
            function (request: any) {
              request.headers = {
                'x-api-key': keyValue
              }
              return request;
            }
```